# ID потоков на разных ядрах C#

Tags: c#

Уникален ли ID потоков на разных ядрах C#? У меня в приложении над которым работаю есть ряд именованных потоков, запущенных на разных ядрах, мне нужно как то различить их между собой.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Я так понимаю, Windows? Я вот лично не уверен, что разные версии этой ОС не делали это по-разному.

Comment: Дать разные имена? Положить их в коллекцию, например `Thread[]`, и обращаться по индексу?

Comment: @AK Да виндовс, работает программка только под последней серверной версией

Comment: @aepot нет нужны одинаковые имена

Comment: Вряд-ли кто-то ответит, потому что потоки на низком уровне уже никто не использует, управление потоками доверяют пулу потоков, и обычно используют [асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async) `async/await` на базе асинхронной модели с использованием `Task` (TAP). Поэтому фишка с именованными потоками устарела и давно не используется.

Comment: `Уникален ли ID потоков на разных ядрах C#?` Да, у каждого потока свой уникальный айдишник, независимо от ядра, на котором этот поток работает.

Comment: А зачем различать по айди? Сравнивайте между собой _объекты_ типа `Thread`. Айдишник вроде тоже уникальный, но если поток умер и потом снова создан, то нет гарантии, что его айди не будет повторно использован: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8KQ0iv https://dotnetfiddle.net/zHtdn9

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответы.
@aepot Не столь уж это низко уровнено, у нас есть в проекте, и то и другое, вполне хорошо уживается все)